# Use default Wordpress translations in plugin

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I'm using some strings which are already translated in most WordPress language packs (such as 'Bulk Actions', 'Apply', etc.) and would like to use those translations in my plugin automatically instead of defining them in my custom domain.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it anywhere on the docs, but I've seen it done before by simply omitting the text domain.

So, if you want to provide your own translation for a string you would do this:

```php
__( 'Hello world', 'your-text-domain' );
```

If you want to use a translation provided by WordPress core:

```php
__( 'Apply' ); // no text domain
```